# Excel VBA autofill just return the formula

Tags: excel, autofill, vlookup, vba

I've created a macro and put it in the personal.xls file.
The macro suppose to autofill the vlookup of J column in PhanCong.xls, but it just return exactly the formula.
Here are a part of my Excel file, to illustrate what I say.

[image]

The first column should have the vlookup value, rather than the formula like that.
Here are my macro, the part which autofill data.

```
        "C:\Users\khoale\Desktop\PhanCong.xls"
Windows("test.xlsx").Activate
ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 1).Activate
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=VLOOKUP(RC[9],'[PhanCong.xls]Bang ma CC'!C1:C7,7,FALSE)"
Dim autoFillRow As Long
With ActiveSheet
autoFillRow = .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End With
Range("A2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:A" & autoFillRow), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

Comment: What is the `Format` of the destination column?

Comment: I've formatted it with this Columns("A:A").NumberFormat = "@"

Comment: I tried to format it as Text, so if that line is wrong, please correct me.

Comment: Try `General`. `Text` treats everything as text and will not evaluate it.

Comment: omg, such a simple solution. Thank you for you help. Since it just a comment, so I only can vote your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cell format `Text` treats the value of the cell just as text. It will not evaluate any formulas. If you want it to be evaluated I think you have to use `General`. (not 100% certain)

<strike>If you need to format the result as text, I beleive you can do this.</strike>

`=TEXT(VLOOKUP(RC[9],'[PhanCong.xls]Bang ma CC'!C1:C7,7,FALSE))`

Just gave it a go and no, it wont help!